# Date_diff with specific condition time start and time end

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

is it possible to have date_diff with specific start and end time?

let say my store are open from 8AM - 10PM, which is 14 Hours.
and I have a lot of stuff to sell during that time. One of the SKU is out of stock from 2022-11-01 06.00 PM until tomorrow 2022-11-02 11.00 AM.

Instead of calculate 24 hours, I just want to calculate only from opening store until it closed or until its restock. Meaning from 6PM to 11AM is 8 Hours

my query

`select date_diff('2022-11-02 11.00 AM', '2022-11-02 06.00 PM', hour) from table`

with the result 17 hours instead of 8 hours

Comment: I have left you a general answer. Ideally questions should usually contain some code (a 'minimal reproducible example') showing what you've tried so far/what you're trying to achieve. As written, your question is quite vague so I can only give you general advice. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for all the guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to configure `DATE_DIFF` to do this for you, but [it's possible to do what you want, with some effort](https://docs.getdbt.com/blog/measuring-business-hours-sql-time-on-task).

You should convert your dates to timestamps (`TIMESTAMP(yourdate)` or `CAST(yourdate AS TIMESTAMP)`) and use [TIMESTAMP_DIFF](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#timestamp_diff) instead.

This will allow you to work with smaller intervals than days.

For your calculation, you ultimately need to find the total time difference between the two timestamps and then subtract the out-of-hours timeframe.

However, calculating the latter is not as simple as taking the difference in days and multiplying by 8 hours (10pm-6am), because your out-of-hours calculation has to account for weekends and possibly holidays etc. Hence it can get quite complex, which is where the solution in my first link might come in.

Comment: actually date_diff(date, date, day) is the same, my point is how to calculate 
2022-11-01 06.00 PM until 2022-11-02 11.00 AM become 8 hours, instead of 17 Hours

Comment: Oh I see. Well the short answer is 'no, date_diff doesn't support that'. But there is a way. I'll add it to my answer.